# Setting LS_COLORS and in a GNU Screen

Tags: bash, osx, gnu-screen

Is there a way to set a GNU Screen LS_COLORS to that of the default non-screen terminal window?

Is there `.screenrc` or `.screen_profile`, I don't understand what happens when a GNU Screen is initialized?

Comment: There is a `~/.screenrc` file, but it is not a shell script, it is read by `screen` with its own command set.  Do you see something different using screen and not?  I've had no problem with the default LS_COLORS for years, on different OSs.

Comment: Yes, the LS_COLORS are set different and vim syntax highlighting changes as well.  [Here](https://github.com/rudolph9/dotfiles) are my dotfiles.

Comment: Could you show the two different values of `LS_COLORS`?  Your `.aliases` file explicitly sets `LS_COLORS`, so it could be something to do with the macos version of `screen` changing the `OSTYPE` value (but that doesn't seem likely.  My suggestion to you is to diff the output of `env` (after proper sorting) inside and outside of `screen` and see what turns up.

Comment: It turns out I had an issue with my dotfiles, in my `.bash_promp` I removed the following and all is well: `if [[ $COLORTERM = gnome-* && $TERM = xterm ]] && infocmp gnome-256color >/dev/null 2>&1; then export TERM=gnome-256color
elif infocmp xterm-256color >/dev/null 2>&1; then export TERM=xterm-256color
fi`.  Still different but it doesn't just make everything red.

Comment: I still don't understand what happens when a GNU Screen is initialized?  If anyone can explain that, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: One thing is that `$TERM` is set to "`screen`".  The default termcap/terminfo entry for "screen" should be the same as xterm-color (in general).  But it can be modified.  I often reset `$TERM` to "xterm" if the shell detects "screen".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to tests with screen on both Linux and FreeBSD, only `~/.bashrc` is sourced. The `~/.bash_profile` is not sourced as not being a "logging shell".

You can easily do this test yourself by adding the right echo lines at the beginning of all your `~/.*rc`.

If you are still unsure of the things or you want screen to set some specific environment, your can use the following "~/.screenrc" options:

- `shell <shell_bin>` to specify the shell binary to use (instead of the default: `$SHELL`)
- `setenv <var> <value>` to set the environment `<var>` to `<value>`
- `source <file>` to source another `<file>`

You can have a look at the other available `~/.screenrc` options in `man screen`, but not much is specificly said about the sourced `~/.*rc` files as it is imply that screen is invoquing a "non-logging shell".

Comment: Note that `source` here means to source another `screenrc` file, not to source a bash script (e.g. `~/.bashrc`).